# amazon-ivs-web-broadcast voice of host is getting recorded but voice of attendees person is not recorded

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webrtc, video-streaming, amazon-ivs

I am using amazon-ivs-web-broadcast.js(https://web-broadcast.live-video.net/1.6.0/amazon-ivs-web-broadcast.js) to record meetings, when i see the live stream, voice of host is coming but voice of another person who is attending the meeting is not coming on live stream
Can some one help do we need extra configuration for capturing attendees voice in IVS

Here is my code

```
async createBroadcast(resolution: string,channelType: string) {
        if(typeof window != "undefined" && window.IVSBroadcastClient){
            try {
                const streamConfig = this.getConfigFromResolution(resolution,channelType);
                this.broadcastClient = window.IVSBroadcastClient?.create({
                    streamConfig: streamConfig
                  })
                
                return this.broadcastClient;
              } catch (error) {
                this.errorMsg = IVSErrorMsg.error_creating_stream
              }
        }
    }
```

```
    async createVideoStream(name: string,deviceId: string) {

      try {
        if(this.broadcastClient && this.broadcastClient.getVideoInputDevice(name)){
          const videoStreamOld = this.broadcastClient.getVideoInputDevice(name);
          for (const track of videoStreamOld.source.getVideoTracks()) {
            track.stop();
          }
          await this.broadcastClient.removeVideoInputDevice(name);
        }
        const videoStream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
          video: {
            deviceId: { exact: deviceId },
            width: {
             ideal: widthVideo.ideal,
             max: widthVideo.max,
           },
           height: {
             ideal: heightVideo.ideal,
             max: heightVideo.max,
           },
          aspectRatio: aspectVideo.ideal,
          frameRate: frameRateVideo,
          },
          audio: true,
        });
        if (this.broadcastClient) await this.broadcastClient.addVideoInputDevice(videoStream, name, { index: 0 });
  
      } catch (error) {
        this.errorMsg = IVSErrorMsg.error_adding_video
      }
     };
```

```
    async createAudioStream(name: string,deviceId: string) {
     
         try {   
         
        if (this.broadcastClient && this.broadcastClient.getAudioInputDevice(name)) {
     
         const audioStreamOld = this.broadcastClient.getAudioInputDevice(name);
         for (const track of audioStreamOld.source.getAudioTracks()) {
          track.stop();
         }
     
         await this.broadcastClient.removeAudioInputDevice(name);
       }
       
         const audioStream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
         audio: {
           deviceId
         },
       });
       if (this.broadcastClient) await this.broadcastClient.addAudioInputDevice(audioStream,name);
         } catch (error) {
           console.log("error",error)
         }
         
    };
```

```
 const init = async () => {
      try {
        broadcastClient?.createBroadcast(resolution,channelType);
       
        await createVideoStream(CAM_LAYER_NAME,devices.webcam.id);
        await createAudioStream(MIC_LAYER_NAME,devices.speaker.id);
        await startBroadcast(stream_key,ingest_server)
      } catch (error) {
        console.log("error",error)
      }

    
    };
```